# How to remove redundant grub from a GPT hard drive?

Tags: bootloader, grub2, gpt, windows-server-2012

I once installed Debian onto my hard drive with GPT so there is a grub on it. Recently I erased Debian and install Windows Server 2012. But the grub is still there (which can launch nothing and I am using Windows Bootloader). How can I remove it? Can the command `bootrec /fixmbr` work on GPT hard drive? Thank you.